# Rhomobile add buttons and toolbar to mapview

Tags: android-mapview, rhomobile

I am using Rhodes 3.1.0 and trying to implement some mapViews on my App.

From the [tutorial](http://docs.rhomobile.com/mapping-tutorial) I can display the map correctly with all the points I need. Now what I need to do is add some extra buttons/toolbar there so the user can perform some desired actions.

I haven't been able to find any information about this. I have been asking on Rhomobile's Google Group, but haven't got any good answers yet.

I got a suggestion to try [this example app](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes-system-api-samples), but the app stops responding or I get an error when I try to view the Map.

Any help on how to add additional buttons to the view is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra buttons can only be added on the working master branch. It does not work on the current release version of Rhodes 3.1.

If you try the [example app](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes-system-api-samples) with the master branch version you will be able to see the extra features.

The source code can be installed following [these instructions](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/build#setting-up-rhodes-source-code)

Answer (score 0):

Related to your other question, I think the way to handle this will be to have the URL for your pin point to a controller and action within your application in the form "/app/Controller/action".

Comment: Thanks, but the actions I want the user to perform are not always related to an specific pin, for example search for one of the pins displayed on the map.